# How to find $\operatorname E(X^2\mid X)$?

Tags: statistics, expected-value

I have to find $\operatorname{Var}(Y\mid X)$ where $Y = c + βX$. What I have so far is:
\begin{align}
\operatorname{Var}(Y\mid X) & = \operatorname E(Y^2\mid X) - \operatorname E(Y\mid X)^2 \\
& = \operatorname  E(c^2 + 2c\beta X + (\beta^2)(X^2) \mid X) - (c^2 + 2c\beta X + (\beta^2)(X^2)).
\end{align}
I know the first part of the last equation is $c^2 + 2cβX + (β^2) \operatorname E(X^2\mid X)$. I'm not sure how to do the $(β^2) \operatorname E(X^2\mid X)$ part.

Comment: Please use relevant titles (and, if I may add, relevant tags).

Answer (score 1):

$$\operatorname{E}[X^2 \mid X] = X^2.$$

Comment: But then Var(Y|X) would be 0. Isn't E[X^2∣X] different from E[X|X]^2?

Comment: @EthanSmith : If $Y=c+\beta X$ and $c$ and $\beta$ are not random, then $\operatorname{var}(Y\mid X)=0$ since $Y$ is completely determined by $X. \qquad$

Comment: This is what I've done although it's not 0, it makes sense to me. What's wrong with this?                                                                                   
E(Y^2|X) - (E(Y|X))^2 =   E(c^2 + 2cβX + β^2X^2) - (E(c+ βX))^2 =                                                                  c^2 +2cβX + β^2E(X^2) - c^2 - 2cβX - β^2E(X)2) = β^2(E(X^2) - E(X)^2) = (β^2)Var(X) = (β^2)σ^2